# Unexpected ';' token JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Im new to JS and can't understand why Im getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;" when calculating the first tip.

```
var bill1,bill2,bill3,
    tip1,tip2,tip3,
    total1,total2,total3;

bill1 = 124;
bill2 = 48;
bill3 = 50;

//Tip calculator
function tipCalc(x){
  if(x < 50){
    return x * .2;
  } else if(x >= 50 && x < 200){
     return x * .15;
  } else (x > 200)
     return x * .1;
}


//Just the tip
tip1 = (tipCalc(bill1);  <----here
tip2 = (tipCalc(bill2);
tip3 = (tipCalc(bill3);
```

Edit: I am dumb, and sleep deprived

Comment: There are unbalanced parentheses on the last three lines. The first opening parenthesis on each line is useless and it does not have a matching closing parenthesis.

Comment: Not wanting to be rude, but you should consider learning the basics, do online tutorials (e.g. with https://www.learn-js.org/) before posting questions.
On your three last lines, just after your `=` signs, you have unnecessary opening parentheses that are not matched by closing ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis `)`.  Make sure you close every one that you open.

```
tip1 = (tipCalc(bill1));  <----here
```

Comment: Or, OP can remove the opening parenthesis after the equal sign like this instead: `tip1 = tipCalc(bill1);`

Comment: @ionizer Yes, for sure.

Comment: I'm blown away ... a +100k user answer a _typo kind of question_ and on top gets 4 upvotes. Where are we going here at SO?

Comment: @LGSon I wanted to answer the question to get this person started. You'll also note that I voted to close the question as well, at the same time.